# Не подгружаются данные при достижении конца списка

Tags: java, android, json

Есть listener :

```
    public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 20;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startingPageIndex, int currentPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startingPageIndex;
        this.currentPage = currentPage;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            loading = onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }      
}
```

И есть класс, который подгружает данные с JSON :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static ArrayList<Model_Melodies.Melodies> melodiesList;
private Model_Melodies melodies;
private ListView mListView;
private AdapterListMelodies adapter;
private int countItems=0;
// public String JSON_URL = "https://api-content-beeline.intech-global.com" +
//"/public/marketplaces/1/tags/4/melodies/?limit=20&from=" + //countItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    melodies = new Model_Melodies();
    melodies.setMelodies(melodiesList);
    melodiesList = new ArrayList<>();
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new AdapterListMelodies(MainActivity.this,melodiesList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    customLoadMoreDataFromApi(countItems);
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int page) {
    countItems = page;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new 
    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "https://api-content-beeline.intech-global.com" +
                    "/public/marketplaces/1/tags/4/melodies/?limit=20&from=" + countItems,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                toList(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}

public ArrayList toList(JSONObject response) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray values = response.getJSONArray("melodies");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) values.get(i);
        melodiesList.add(new Model_Melodies.Melodies(
                o.getString("picUrl"), o.getString("title"), o.getString("artist"), o.getString("demoUrl")));
    }
    return melodiesList;
}
}
```

адаптер

```
public class AdapterListMelodies extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Model_Melodies.Melodies> items;
private DisplayImageOptions options;

public AdapterListMelodies(Context context, ArrayList<Model_Melodies.Melodies> items) {
    mContext = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, parent, false);
        holder= new ViewHolder();

        holder.nameArtist= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nameArtist);
        holder.nameSounds = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nameSounds);
        holder.cover = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }
    Model_Melodies.Melodies modelMelodiesMelodies = items.get(position);
    holder.nameArtist.setText(modelMelodiesMelodies.getArtist());
    holder.nameSounds.setText(modelMelodiesMelodies.getTitle());

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(modelMelodiesMelodies.getPicUrl(), holder.cover, options);

    return v;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView cover;
    public TextView nameArtist;
    public TextView nameSounds;
}
}
```

Но данные не загружаются(( подскажите, что сделал не так?

Comment: Как я понял данные таки загружаются, а вот адаптер не отображает новые данные?..

Comment: да, у меня при скролле в конце списка просто копирует старые данные в новые 20 элементов

Comment: Очень странно вот это выглядит: `public String JSON_URL = "https://api-content-beeline.intech-global.com" +
        "/public/marketplaces/1/tags/4/melodies/?limit=20&from=" + countItems;` с последующим изменением цифры в конце. Попробуйте формировать адрес запроса целиком в момент начала запроса, а не меняя переменную. Возможно тут дело именно в этом. Вы ж не раскрываете информации о том чему это число равно в процессе работы программы.

Comment: в смысле каждый раз менять значение строки? да я не скрываю, что за значение, countItems это получается отступ  с которого начинается загрузка.
 задача такая: отобразить список с несколькими параметрами. Для пагинации
к запросу добавляются параметры limit и from (пример: .../melodies?limit=10&from=0). При первом запросе нужно получить 20 песен, затем подгружать следующие по необходимости при прокрутке. можете показать как примерно должен выглядеть код?
Изначально число равно 0, и потом счетчик должен увеличиваться

Comment: Я имею в виду, что вы недостаточно ясно очертили проблему и приходится гадать где она у вас именно. Так что попробуйте так: `final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://api-content-beeline.intech-global.com" + "/public/marketplaces/1/tags/4/melodies/?limit=20&from=" + countItems`

Comment: попробовал, не помогло. а что это изменило? если она отдельно вынесена в переменную или напрямую записана?

Comment: мне кажется проблема в другом, вот в этом 
melodies.setMelodies(melodiesList);
                        adapter = new AdapterListMelodies(MainActivity.this, toList(values));
                        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 так как по идее должно быть что при обновлении адаптер должен просто обновляться, а не назначаться заново, но как это сделать не понимаю

Comment: Ну, вообще да, надо данные хранить спском в активити, например, и, когда новые приходят, добавлять их в этот список. После чего уведомлять адаптер не пересоздавая его.

Comment: так я так и делаю ведь

Comment: Вы в `customLoadMoreDataFromApi` каждый раз новый адаптер назначаете. Плюс неизвестно что у вас в адаптере... Сложно вычленить где у вас ошибка.

Comment: почему не понятно что в адаптере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы объявили `JSON_URL` один раз. Она у вас константа. То, что вы меняете `countItems` на `JSON_URL` никак не влияет.
2. `Volley.newRequestQueue(this)` каждый раз вызывать не надо. Ее вообще надо один раз объявить в синглтоне каком-нить (Application например).
3. В адаптер у вас передается `melodiesList` по ссылке, поэтому создавать каждый раз адаптер нет необходимости. Создайте его один раз в onCreate. Дальше наполняйте `melodiesList` при вызовах api и вызывайте у адаптера `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
4. Стоит все-таки разобраться что такое from в url. Страница или смещение.

ЗЫ Volley хорошая библиотека..., вот если бы она еще умела onResponse вызывать в не в главном потоке...

```
public final int LIMIT = 20;
public final String BASE_URL = "https://api-content-beeline.intech-global.com";
public final String JSON_URL = BASE_URL+
    "/public/marketplaces/1/tags/4/melodies/?limit=%d&from=%d";

private void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int page) {
    countItems = LIMIT*page;
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, 
        String.format(JSON_URL, LIMIT, countItems),
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: from в данном случае смещение

Comment: а мне сказали что onResponse  вызывается в отдельном потоке..., тогда лучше вызвать его в AsyncTask?

Comment: нет, сам запрос выполняется в отдельном потоке, а onResponse в главном (иначе у вас была бы ошибка обращения к UI элементам не из главного потока). Просто формирование melodiesList у вас, к примеру, может затянуться и приводить к лагам вплоть до ANR, но это меньшая из ваших проблем, это была жалоба на жизнь так сказать...

Comment: если from у вас смещение, то формируйте JSON_URL перед каждым запросом, подставляя в него countItems, предварительно рассчитав смещение по номеру страницы, вы же страницу передаете...

Comment: можно уточнить по 1 пункту. countItems=0 переменная класса, изначально равна 0, потом при вызове метода ей передается номер страницы и по идее она должна менять значение, почему же она не влияет ни на что вы говорите?
по поводу последнего комментария, я немного не понял, при каждом вызове customLoadMoreDataFromApi у меня итак заново считывается строка, и она каждый раз разная, так как ей присваивается значения page ? 
можете на примере показать, что значит рассчитать? ведь я итак передаю номер страницы? и как только номер страницы достигает заданного, то по идее должна вызываться подгрузка

Comment: метод toList по хорошему значит надо переносить в отдельный поток?

Comment: подправил код, теперь каждый раз у меня у меня формируется новый запрос, но данные все равно копируются, хотя уже не с 1 элемента, а с 3 или больше..

Comment: Внес изменения в ответ. Если на странице 20 элементов, то надо прибавлять не по 1, а по 20...

Comment: Что касается отдельного потока для toList, то на 20 элементах скорее всего задержка будет небольшой... Когда придумаете грузить по 100 элементов и или в базу кэшировать подгрузку, можно будет вынести в отдельный поток, пока можно не заморачиваться.

Comment: можете посоветовать литературу почитать по данному вопросу? чтобы подобные ошибки больше не возникали?

Comment: Спасибо большое!! теперь работает как надо!

Comment: По андроиду Харди и Филлипс. А так дело опыта... Дерзайте.

Comment: я его как раз читаю)  спасибо) а то думал не хватает каких-то определенных знаний..
вернее их итак не хватает, так как только разбираюсь с данной темой..